# How to pass string javascript variable to get web.config values

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying following code to get web.config value in an MVC view.

```
function GetMinMax(Code) {
    var newCode= Code;
    var minCode =newCode+"MinValue";
    var maxCode =newCode+"MaxValue";

    var minValue = @Convert.ToInt32(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[minCode]);
    var maxValue = @Convert.ToInt32(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[maxCode]);
    return [minValue, maxValue];
}
```

However the javscript variables `minCode` and `maxCode` is undefined. Please let me know if it is possible to achieve.

Comment: I really surprised why i got a down vote for this code. When my following code works perfect under document.ready ??? `var minRange = @Convert.ToInt32(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PriceMinRange"]);
        var maxRange = @Convert.ToInt32(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MaxRange"]);
        var minVal = @Convert.ToInt32(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MinSelectedValue"]);
        var maxVal = @Convert.ToInt32(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MaxSelectedValue"]);`

Comment: I haven't downvoted the question but I guess that the person who did it is because of your lack of understanding the difference between what executes on the server and on the client. Javascript vs server side code. That's not a reason for a downvote IMHO.

Comment: Ya got it. I was aware that the razor allows us to write server side codes embedded inside JS or HTML views. If I hard code `AppSettings["MaxSelec‌​tedValue"]`. It works perfectly here too. I just wanted that to be dynamic :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot get web.config values directly from javascript. That would have been a huge security vulnerability if it was possible. Just think about it.

If you want to do that you will have to make an AJAX request to the server passing your javascript variable (`code`) to the server which will in turn look up the configuration value in web.config and return the result to the client:

```
function GetMinMax(code, callback) {
    var minValueKey = code + 'MinValue';
    var maxValueKey = code + 'MaxValue';

    $.getJSON(
        '/some_controller/some_action', 
        { 
            minValueKey: minValueKey, 
            maxValueKey: maxValueKey 
        }, 
        callback
    );
}
```

and your corresponding action:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(string minValueKey, string maxValueKey) 
{
    int minValue = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[minValueKey]);
    int maxValue = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[maxValueKey]);

    var result = new[] { minValue, maxValue };
    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

and here's how you would consume the function on the client:

```
GetMinMax('SomeCode', function(result) {
    // do something with the result here => it will be an array with 2 elements
    // the min and max values
    var minValue = result[0];
    var maxValue = result[1];

    alert('minValue: ' + minValue + ', maxValue: ' + maxValue);
});
```

Comment: I wonder then how my this code works under document.ready  ,  `var minRange = @Convert.ToInt32(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PriceMin‌​Range"]); var maxRange = @Convert.ToInt32(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MaxRange‌​"]); var minVal = @Convert.ToInt32(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MinSelec‌​tedValue"]); var maxVal = @Convert.ToInt32(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MaxSelec‌​tedValue"]);`

Comment: Your code works in document.ready because you have hardcoded the key passed to the ConfigurationManager: `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PriceMin‌​‌​Range​"]`. Notice how `PriceMin‌​‌​Range` is a hardcoded string. Now look at the code in your question: `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[minCode]`. See the difference? This `minCode` that you are passing as key is a javascript variable. You are attempting to pass a javascript variable to a function that executes on the server which makes absolutely no sense whatsoever. That's why your code doesn't work

Comment: So I guess I can indeed get web.config values from javascript :) Anyways thanks for the code provided. So can you please tell me can that PriceMin‌​‌​Range be dynamic?

Comment: Yes, it can. That's exactly what I have shown in my answer. Did you read it? You need to make an AJAX request to the server passing the javascript value.